# How to share ubuntu (make server (Ruby on Rails)) in home, on virtual machine?

Tags: file-sharing, ruby, rails, home-server

how can I share my ubuntu server () which is installed on virtual machine. Main machine is asus k52de, which OS is Windows 7 professional. How can i do, that i can attach to my ubuntu from another computer anywhere? I have non-static IP, and I want to use no-ip free technology. Help me please to do this. At first I want to install file server, then Ruby on Rails (for our university people small group).Also internet for mu asus goes via WI-Fi router.
in virtual is bridge method
ip of ubuntu on virtual: 192.168.1.4
of note 192.168.1.3
of pc (is in same local) 192.168.1.2

my question is how to ACCESS this ubuntu on virtualbox from WEB!

Comment: VirtualBox, Client for windows no-ip

Answer (score 1):

That's a lot for one question... Nothing you are looking to do sounds unreasonable.  Keep in mind, the VM will only be available externally when both the windows 7 and the ubuntu vm are running.  When you run a VM, both the Host (windows 7 in your case) and the Guest OS (the ubuntu) need to run simultaneously.  This means you will have to have enough CPU to run both and RAM memory (probably need at least 2GB for both to be comfortable).

For the VM, I recommend you try VirtualBox to host the VM.  It is free for individual use.  Get it here: https://www.virtualbox.org/

Install the virtualbox software on your windows 7.  Then you will need to download the ISO for the ubuntu that you would like to use.  Basically, you will need to go into virtualbox and start a new VM.  Choose linux + ubuntu for the type of guest and then you need to set your ISO to mount as a CD drive.  Start the VM and install Ubuntu. Plenty of tutorials are out there on that.

For the non-static ip issue, you could try DynDns.  They associate a subdomain of one of their domains with your server.  Then you run a small daemon on the ubuntu that periodically updates Dyndns with your current IP address. Then when someone accesses you dyndns address, they get sent to your server.  I have used it successfully for a number of years now. I think they let you set up a few subdomains on a free account.

Good luck!

Comment: I know it without you, my question is how to ACCESS this ubuntu on virtualbox from WEB!

Comment: Port forward your Webhost to the router and enable WAN access for the protocols required. I have written about it [here - Accessing your local web server files apache2/tomcat6 from an external network in Linux: How-to](http://thevoidghost.wordpress.com/2011/06/09/accessing-your-local-web-server-files-apache2tomcat6-from-an-external-network-in-linux-how-to-especially-on-a-beetel-220bxi-modem/), feel free to check it out.

Comment: dyndns without credit card is not available

Comment: @pavel You could always try http://www.no-ip.com/